# How to avoid arg kwargs to be non mutable?

Tags: python, mutable, keyword-argument

I have a class A

```
class A:
  __dict__ = {"x": 0}

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs.copy())
```

When I create A objects:

```
>>> a = A(x=2)
>>> b = A(x=3)
>>> print(a.__dict__)
{x: 3}
>>> print(b.__dict__)
{x: 3}
```

When I preset **dict** without **init**, it becomes mutable, how can I avoid that?

Comment: maybe add a more elaborate example, showing an expected an actual outputs?

Comment: You do not create any reference to the object, so it garbage collected and the same memory is used for the new object, resulting in the same ID.

Comment: Why are you accessing `__dict__` directly?

Comment: To make it something like default argument, because I want `A` to be inherited

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dict.copy()` to get a new (shallow!) copy of `kwargs`, like this:

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.local_copy = kwargs.copy()
    print(id(self.local_copy))

a2 = A(x=2)
a3 = A(x=3)
print(a2.local_copy)
print(a3.local_copy)
```

example output:

```
15067008
15031824
{'x': 2}
{'x': 3}
```

**EDIT:**
as @chepner pointed out in the comments, the `copy` is unnecessary.
I assume the reason you get the same `id` for the 2 different invocations is that kwargs is unreferenced once the function returns, so the object may be garbage collected, and its address is reused.

even without copy, I get the same results: (2 different IDs, and distinct A objects)

Comment: I tried this but when I update object's dict object with that copy, it doesn't copy

Comment: It's a shallow copy

Comment: You don't need a copy of `kwargs`; it is already a brand new `dict` created from the given keyword arguments.

Comment: @chepner you are very much correct! so I guess when it is not saved anywhere, the same memory is just reused for the next call to `__init__`?

Comment: The same memory may or may not be reused; it doesn't matter one way or the other.